# Clearing Cin buffer not working

Tags: c++, buffer, cin

I am working on a the beginnings of a menu program, and I am having trouble clearing the cin buffer. I have tried cin.ignore,sync, clear, and several other things. I do not under stand why this loop does not wait for an input, and just repeats infinity.

```
do
{
    cout << "Enter One of the Following Choices: \n"<<
    "A: Carnivore       C: Pianist\n" <<
    "B: Tree            D: Game\n"<< "You must enter A,B,C,D: \n";
    //getline(cin,tmp);cin.ignore();cin.sync();cin.clear();
    cin.get(choice);

}while(choice!='A' && choice!='B' && choice!='C' && choice!='D');
```

Comment: What is the type of `choice`?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `cin >> choice`?

Comment: I tried that as well, causes the same error

Comment: Check if cin has some error flag set. If yes clear the error.

Comment: sorry I am kinda of new to c++ , how do i do that?

Comment: You can check this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear

Comment: i add a cin.good;cin.clear;cin.good, before the get, this made it so that it run 3 times before waiting for input , it had 01, 11, 11, as the outputs for the good:clear;good ( i had good print to screen so first number is for the first good and the second number is for second good)